# Delay tactics in which others benefit team from your efforts

Tags: phrases, expressions

I came across a delay tactic in which other team benefit from your team's efforts.

Lets say:

Team leaders of two teams A & B are given same assignment with a deadline by a boss.

Team leader of A team starts mobilizing on strategies to accomplish them,  he even formulates the concept and team A works on it and finishes the task by the deadline.

Team B leader and the team B does not do anything.

Due to historical bias, looking at the efficient team, the boss would in fact ask team A of the status over the other. The point is due to the delay tactics used by team B the whole department rips benefit from Team A efforts.

I want to know what would you call such a delay tactic?

Comment: Historical bias of expecting success and taking it for granted?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following term.

### play a waiting game

As mentioned in [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/play-a-waiting-game),
the definition of this idiom is:

> to delay making any decisions or taking any action, because you think that it is better to wait and see how things develop.

There won't be an exact idiom/term of "waiting for the other team to complete the task and copy them". But, this is the closest to it.

Example usage of this idiom in a sentence:

> The moderates are playing a waiting game and the longer they wait, the more marginal their party is going to start to seem.

Comment: You have failed to correctly reference material written by others. [Please review our Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and edit your post accordingly.